# Check if a value is a Keyword List

Tags: elixir

Elixir provides a few `is_` functions that let you check if an item is a specific type:

- `is_atom`
- `is_binary`
- `is_map`
- etc.

**But how do I check if a value is a Keyword List in Elixir?** I understand that underneath, Keyword Lists are a list of 2-element tuples with the first element as an atom, so my current workaround is this:

```ex
defmodule KList do
  def is_keyword?(list) when is_list(list) do
    Enum.all? list, fn item ->
      case item do
        {k, _} -> is_atom(k)
        _      -> false
      end
    end
  end

  def is_keyword?(_), do: false
end
```

**Is there a better (or an in-built) way of doing this? And more importantly, how can I do this in a `when` clause?**

Comment: You won't be able to check for a keyword list in a guard clause. There is a predefined list of expressions allowed in guards. The only extension you are allowed to write is macros that expand to those allowed expressions. http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/guards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out there *is* a built in solution; the `Keyword` module exports a `keyword?/1` method:

> **[Keyword.keyword?(term)](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Keyword.html#keyword?/1)**
>
> Returns `true` if `term` is a keyword list; otherwise returns `false`

**Example:**

```ex
iex> Keyword.keyword?([])
true
iex> Keyword.keyword?([a: 1]
true
iex> Keyword.keyword?([{Foo, 1}])
true
iex> Keyword.keyword?([{}])
false
iex> Keyword.keyword?([:key])
false
iex> Keyword.keyword?(%{})
false
```

---

**Note:** *Unlike other `is_` exports in the Kernel, `keyword?` is **not** a macro – that means it cannot be used in guards.*